# Personalization in EXM works partially in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: exm, personalization

I just created a sample newsletter regular email campaign with personalization. I added the rule **When the current month is**. The mail is sent successfully. But When I view the mail, the mail shows default content like below [image]
But when I clicked the following link in the mail **Are you having trouble viewing the email? Please click here to see the online version.** it shows personalized content like below.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Sitecore 9.0.1, there is a bug that prevents personalization from working. My advice is that you file a Support Ticket and reference Sitecore Hotfix 219515, or upgrade to Sitecore 9.1